# Django Admin modifications

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have an app in which two models are related with foreign keys.

```
class Trans(models.Model):
    pk = UUIDField(auto=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, hyphenate=True)
    en = models.TextField('English')


class Article(models.Model):
    pk = UUIDField(auto=True, primary_key=True, serialize=True, hyphenate=True)
    title = models.OneToOneField(Trans)
    description = models.OneToOneField(Trans)
```

Now if I want to add values in Article model via admin interface and for title and description there will be a **'+'** sign above the field to add values , on click Trans model form popup will shown where I can add values and then that instance will be attach into Article title field (Usual process).

But I do not want to add values like this , I want to show a simple text field to admin there for both title and description and on save those values saved into Trans model and their instance in Article model . In simple words I do not want to show **'+'** sign to admin but a simple text field.

Is this possible in Django admin if yes then any suggestions ?

Comment: You need [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid My models are related with  `OneToOneField` , so  `InlineModelAdmin`  works in this case ?